# How to show a Kendo UI for Angular combobox open and use an *ngIf directive in it

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

ComboBoxComponent provides the method toggle that toggles the visibility of the comboBox popup. I want to display comboBox already opened. I have the following implementation:

**datalist.component.html**

```
<kendo-combobox #attributecombobox></kendo-combobox>
```

**datalist.component.cs**

```
@Component({    
    templateUrl: './datalist.component.html'
})
export class DatalistComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('attributecombobox') public attributeCombobox: ComboBoxComponent;
}
```

I've tried setting the constructor:

```
constructor() {
   this.attributeCombobox.toggle(true);
}
```

Doesn't work. I also tried the OnInit lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.attributeCombobox.toggle(true);
}
```

It also does not work.

What is the right approach for this? Thanks in advance.

### Update 1

Sorry, I didn't disclose all the code. The ComboBox actually has a ***ngIf**:

**datalist.component.html**

```
<kendo-combobox #attributecombobox *ngIf="setAttribute"></kendo-combobox>
```

**datalist.component.cs**

```
    @Component({    
        templateUrl: './datalist.component.html'
    })
    export class DatalistComponent implements OnInit {
       @ViewChild('attributecombobox') public attributeCombobox: ComboBoxComponent;
       setAttribute = true;

       ngOnInit() {
           this.attributeCombobox.toggle(true);
       }
    }
```

So I think that I found an issue with **kendo-combobox** elements using ***ngIf** as you can see in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nmHeTQYUv7AaqWNDcviz?p=preview) that I forked from George K plunker (thanks George).

### Update 2

I submitted an issue which was classified as a bug [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/445).

Comment: dont pass a value into toggle, its a parameterless method

Comment: It actually accepts a parameter as you can see in the documentation: [toggle](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ComboBoxComponent/#toc-toggle)

Comment: Indeed, the combobox is not available in ngOnInit hook. This, however, is expected because the combobox is not added yet, due to the structure *ngIf directive. The earliest possible moment to toggle the popup is in the ngAfterViewInit hook - http://plnkr.co/edit/quLb3oeiVRJfqACqGKEK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest possible place to open the component is in the ngOnInit (your second attempt). Calling the [toggle](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ComboBoxComponent/#toc-toggle) method works just fine for me:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.combo.toggle();
}
```

Here is a runnable plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ssbftD6hg3f7LM86CIPD?p=preview

#### Update

Indeed, the component will not be available in `ngOnInit` hook if a structure directive like `ngIf` is applied. Basically, this will desugar to

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="show">....combobox here... </ng-template>
```

As you've probably already noticed, the component inside the template will not be there on first init. The solution is to use a hook that will be called later in the component initialization, like AfterViewInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.combo.toggle();
   });
}
```

The updated plunkr demo can be found here - http://plnkr.co/edit/quLb3oeiVRJfqACqGKEK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for you anwser George, it helped to find a conclusion.

Comment: It worked! Thanks George, I have to learn about Lifecycle Hooks with more attention.